# How to get count of customers?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need some help with an SQL query.
Let's say we have this sample database which manages Bookings in a hotel:

```
Customer(ID, name, birthDate, city);
Room(number, floor, beds, roomtype, price);
Bookings(Customer, roomNumber, floor, checkInDate, checkOutDate);
```

I need to know which customers booked only and ONLY economic type of rooms.
This is my query:

```
select Customer from Bookings
   join Room on(Bookings.num = camera.roomNumber and Bookings.floor= 
   Room.floor)
        where (Bookings.Customer, Bookings.floor) not in (select number, floor from 
        Room where roomType != 'economic')
```

My issue is that this query shows me customers which booked economic rooms, but it also shows me customers which booked other type of rooms.
How can I restrict the output in order to get Customers which booked ONLY economic rooms?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `not exists` :

```
select c.*
from Customer c
where not exists (select 1 
                  from Bookings b
                  inner join Room r on b.num = r.roomNumber and b.floor = r.floor
                  where c.ID = b.Customer and r.roomType <> 'economic'
                  );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation:

```
select b.Customer
from Bookings b join
     Room r
     on b.num = r.roomNumber and b.floor = r.floor
group by b.Customer
having min(roomType) = max(roomType) and min(roomType) = 'economic';
```